# How to overwrite delete method in generics class (DRF)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models: `Wallet` and `Transaction`.The `Wallet` model has many `Transactions`. I want to return the amount of money for that `Wallet` object that `Transactions` belong to. If I delete a transaction. But I don't know how to do that. Below is my class view

```
class TransactionDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    name = 'transaction-detail'
```

Wallet and Transaction model

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='wallets',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
    amount = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta: 
        ordering = ('name',)
    
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        related_name='transactions',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(
        Wallet,
        related_name='transactions',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='transactions', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
    kind = models.ForeignKey(
        KindOfTransaction, 
        related_name='transactions',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag,
        related_name='transactions',
        blank=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    amount = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-updated_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: *"I don't know how to do that"* ... to do what? to override a method in python?

Comment: No, How to add the amount money of transaction to the wallet in belong to after I delete that transaction

Comment: Probably, you should include the related models too

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post